# Using Thor, how can I remove an option for just a few tasks?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

I have a CLI built using Thor. I need a global option for all my tasks except a few. I added the global option by defining a class_option, but I am not able to figure out how to remove that option from a select few tasks. If I use remove_class_option() in one of my tasks, then the global option is removed for good, and no longer available.

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could use the method described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14360552/789593