# How to make two thor tasks share options?

Tags: ruby, thor

With Thor one can use [`method_option`](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Method-Options) to set the options for a particular task. To set the options for all tasks in a class one can use `class_option`. But what about the case where one wants some tasks of a class, but not all, to share options?

In the following `task1` and `task2` shares options but they do not share all options and they share no options with `task3`.

```
require 'thor'

class Cli < Thor
  desc 'task1', 'Task 1'
  method_option :type, :type => :string, :required => true, :default => 'foo'
  def task1
  end

  desc 'task2', 'Task 2'
  method_option :type, :type => :string, :required => true, :default => 'foo'
  method_option :value, :type => :numeric
  def task2
  end

  desc 'task3', 'Task 3'
  method_option :verbose, :type => :boolean, :aliases => '-v'
  def task3
  end
end

Cli.start(ARGV)
```

The problem with stating `method_option :type, :type => :string, :required => true, :default => 'foo'` for both `task1` and `task2` is that it violates [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Is there an idiomatic way of handling this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`method_option` is defined in [thor.rb](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/1f91d12fce7aef74028e2423e991c6c34036d731/lib/thor.rb#L81-L114) and it takes the following parameters according to the documentation:

- `name<Symbol>::` The name of the argument.
- `options<Hash>::` Described below.

Knowing this you can store the parameters to `method_option` in an array and [expand that array into separate parameters](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html#UC) as `method_option` is called.

```
require 'thor'

class Cli < Thor
  shared_options = [:type, {:type => :string, :required => true, :default => 'foo'}]

  desc 'task1', 'Task 1'
  method_option *shared_options
  def task1
  end

  desc 'task2', 'Task 2'
  method_option *shared_options
  method_option :value, :type => :numeric
  def task2
  end

  desc 'task3', 'Task 3'
  method_option :verbose, :type => :boolean, :aliases => '-v'
  def task3
  end
end

Cli.start(ARGV)
```

I have no idea if this is idiomatic and I do not think it is that elegant. Still, it is better than violating the DRY principle.

Comment: good idea, but can we go further and maybe define shared_options class method delegating to method_option + merging the common hash?

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a superclass like this:

```
require 'thor'

class CliBase < Thor
  def self.shared_options

    method_option :verbose,
                  :aliases => '-v',
                  :type => :boolean,
                  :desc => 'Verbose',
                  :default => false,
                  :required => false

  end
end
```

... then subclass as follows:

```
require 'cli_base'

class Cli < CliBase
  desc 'task1', 'Task 1'
  shared_options
  def task1
  end

  desc 'task2', 'Task 2'
  shared_options
  method_option :value, :type => :numeric
  def task2
  end

  desc 'task3', 'Task 3'
  method_option :colors, :type => :boolean, :aliases => '-c'
  def task3
  end
end

Cli.start(ARGV)
```

Comment: Do you really need subclassing here? Why not just defining shared_options in CLI class?

Comment: I think there are many ways to answer the OP. I happen to despise writing code more than once so with my solution, write the base class, put it in a gem and then use it whenever writing another Thor script. After all, -v for verbose is something I will use again outside of a single instance. But sure, you can do it however you like.

Answer (score 3):

So there is a nice dry way to do this now, but may not fall into the requirements of being as **idiomatic**, though I wanted to mention it for anyone looking for a more recent answer.

You can start by using the class_options to set the majority of shared options between your methods:

```
module MyModule
  class Hello < Thor
    class_option :name, :desc => "name", :required => true
    class_option :greet, :desc => "greeting to use", :required => true

    desc "Hello", "Saying hello"
    def say
      puts "#{options[:greet]}, #{options[:name]}!"
    end

    desc "Say", "Saying anything"
    remove_class_option :greet
    def hello
      puts "Hello, #{options[:name]}!"
    end

    def foo
      puts "Foo, #{options[:name]}!"
    end
  end
end
```

The best part about this, is that it pertains to all methods after the declaration. With these set to required, you can see that the first method requires both *greet* and *name*, but **say** and **foo** only require the name.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I used what N.N. answered.
But I found some problems:

If you want to share more than one option as in the example, it doesn't work very well. Imagine you want to share `:value` between task2 and task3. You could create another `shared_options` or you could create an array with the shared options and access it with the shared_option name.

This works but it's verbose and hard to read. I've implemented something small to be able to share options.

```
Cli < Thor  
  class << self
      def add_shared_option(name, options = {})
        @shared_options = {} if @shared_options.nil?
        @shared_options[name] =  options
      end

      def shared_options(*option_names)
        option_names.each do |option_name|
          opt =  @shared_options[option_name]
          raise "Tried to access shared option '#{option_name}' but it was not previously defined" if opt.nil?
          option option_name, opt
        end
      end
    end
    #...commands 
end
```

This creates a hash with the option name as key, and the 'definition' (required, default, etc) as value (which is a hash). This is easily accessible afterwards.

With this, you can do the following:

```
require 'thor'

class Cli < Thor

  add_shared_option :type,  :type => :string, :required => true, :default => 'foo'
  add_shared_option :value, :type => :numeric

  desc 'task1', 'Task 1'
  shared_options :type
  def task1
  end

  desc 'task2', 'Task 2'
  shared_options :type, :value
  def task2
  end

  desc 'task3', 'Task 3'
  shared_options :value
  def task3
  end
end

Cli.start(ARGV)
```

For me it looks more readable, and if the number of commands is bigger than 3 or 4 it's a great improvement.

Answer (score 0):

So as not to type "shared_options" all the time, you can also do this:

```
require 'thor'

class Cli < Thor
  class << self
    private
    def shared_options!
      # list your shared options here
      method_option :opt1, type: :boolean
      method_option :opt2, type: :numeric
      # etc
    end

    # alias original desc so we can call it from inside new desc
    alias_method :orig_desc, :desc

    # redefine desc, calling original desc, and then applying shared_options!
    def desc(*args)
      orig_desc(*args)
      shared_options!
    end
  end

  desc 'task1', 'Task 1'

  def task1
  end

  desc 'task2', 'Task 2'

  def task2
  end

  desc 'task3', 'Task 3'

  def task3
  end
end
```

Or if you don't want acrobatics with method aliasing, you could just define your own method "my_desc" and call that instead of "desc".